# dio error and The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Uint8List)'. - 'Uint8List' is from

Tags: flutter, dio

I am working on an old project of flutter SDK 2.5.3. there are deprecated plugins `call_number, ext_storage, flutter_rounded_date_picker, flutter_webview_plugin, permissions_plugin`, shows as an warning. when I run the project it shows this error. I think this error is for the dio package. But, when I upgrade the plugin then that new dio package is depend on higher version of other packages.
please tell me what I can do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhFaj.png)

Comment: Have you cleaned it?

Comment: You can clean project, delete some plugins in your `pubspec.yaml` then readd it using terminal, ex. `flutter pub add dio` for all deleted plugins. Then run `flutter pub get` in your terminal.

Comment: If you add the plugin using the terminal, the flutter framework will choose the appropriate version.